# Relative function update for adjacent column values

Tags: excel, vba

I have a dynamic table with a basic function to summarize the total value of all entries in recorded in column J. The entry counts vary month to month and the code shown below is how I am totaling everything up.

`SUMTOTAL = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("J2", Range("J2").End(xlDown)))`

I need to take this total amount and use it in an equation in the next column (K in this case) to show what part of the total value all the entries individually represent as a percent Eg( Entry is worth $20 out of $1200 it will display 1.67%). right now I am stuck on how to assign the cell in column J in the formula.

```
ActiveCell.Formula = Range("J2") / SUMTOTAL
Range("K2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("K2:K" & TABLEROW)
```

above is good for one cell, but doesn't update when it fills down to the end of the table. when I try to use an RC[-1] designate I get a name error from presumably not having the SUMTOTAL recognized.
Is this an issue with my J2 cell designation? or do I need to rework the whole code string?

Thank you in advance for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Range("J2") / SUMTOTAL` does not return a formula that can be placed in a cell.  It returns a set value.

To set a formula you need to create a string that can be inserted as a formula.

Also you do not need `AutoFill` just assign them all at once:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("K2:K" & TABLEROW).Formula = "=" & ActiveSheet.Range("J2").Address(0,0) & "/" & SUMTOTAL
```